# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorContextImpl

Tags: java, gradle, jboss, wildfly, bean-validation

In the code of my custom ConstraintValidator I using such constructor

```
 new ConstraintValidatorContextImpl(
        new ArrayList<String>(),
        DefaultTimeProvider.getInstance(),
        PathImpl.createPathFromString(param),
        violation.getConstraintDescriptor());
```

In run time this causes an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorContextImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/hibernate/validator/spi/time/TimeProvider;Lorg/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/path/PathImpl;Ljavax/validation/metadata/ConstraintDescriptor;)
```

I'm added line below in the build.gradle, in dependencies

```
runtime 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.2.Final'
```

but it is not helped.

Comment: Generally, a class ending by Impl must be constructed with a factory. Check tu use the static builder in ConstraintValidatorContext : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html

Comment: Thank you, it helped. That is solution:  context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("message").addPropertyNode("field").addConstraintViolation();

Comment: @ETartaren if that solved your problem, please post what you did as an answer in case someone comes across this same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No need constructor, ConstraintValidatorContextImpl must be constructed with a factory.

That is solution:

```
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("message").addPropertyNode("field")‌​.addConstraintViolation();
```